# generate_series() equivalent in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, auto-generate

I'm trying to search the DB2 equivalent of [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-srf.html) (the PostgreSQL-way of generating rows). I obviously don't want to hard-code the rows with a [VALUES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-values.html) statement.

```
select * from generate_series(2,4);

    generate_series
    -----------------
                    2
                    3
                    4
    (3 rows)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The where clause needs to be a bit more explicit about the bounds of the recursion in order for DB2 to suppress the warning. Here's a slightly adjusted version that does not trigger the warning:

```
with dummy(id) as (
    select 2 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1    
    union all
    select id + 1 from dummy where id < 4
)
select id from dummy
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to write a recursive query that fits :

```
with dummy(id) as (
    select 2 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1    
    union all
    select id + 1 from dummy where id + 1 between 2 and 4
)
select id from dummy
```

The query can be adapted to whatever for(;;) you can dream of.

Comment: Result is ok, but it generates a warning on db2 v9
SQL0347W  The recursive common table expression "LOGINNAME.DUMMY" may contain an infinite loop.  SQLSTATE=01605

Comment: Yes, I also have it in DB2v8. I don't know how to remove it though.