# how do produce counts for every month around a reference date

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 SQL, where I have a reference date - and would like to count distinct individuals that for each monthdiff either side (increasing up  to the START_DT/END_DT) of the REF_DT - return a row, with the month counter.

My base data looks like:

```
ID   REF_DT       START_DT     END_DT
--   ------       --------     ------
1    2000-01-01   1998-01-01   2002-01-01
2    2001-06-01   2001-06-01   2003-06-01
3    2003-01-01   1998-01-01   2005-06-01
4    2002-05-01   2003-01-01   2005-01-01
```

so taking the first row, I return a row for each month around the `REF_DT` that exists between `START_DT` and `END_DT` and return the value of the monthdiff. The first row in my base table would generate:

```
ID   REF_DT       START_DT     END_DT      MONTHDIFF
--   ------       --------     ------      --------- 
1    2000-01-01   1998-01-01   2002-01-01  -24
1    2000-01-01   1998-01-01   2002-01-01  -23
.
.
.
1    2000-01-01   1998-01-01   2002-01-01  24
```

i.e. would produce 48 rows as the `START_DT` and `END_DT` are 24 months either side of the `REF_DT`

I *could* to this query by query i.e.

```
select distinct id, ref_dt,start_dt,end_dt, 
case when ref_dt - 1 month between start_dt and end_dt then -1 end as monthdiff
```

however I would have to manually create 1 row per query. I wish to embed this logic in something a bit more clever than that.

Thanks.

**SOLVED**

see Juan's suggestion for the answer. The idea to create a table for just the month reference worked. I created this table by looking at the following stack thread [generate_series() equivalent in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806689/generate-series-equivalent-in-db2)

Comment: `REF_DT`, `START_DT` and `END_DT` is the same for all `MONTHDIFF` in your desire output?

Comment: @Juan - not they can be different for each person. However I don't mind specifying fixed boundaries before hand, for example 5 years either side as I know this will capture all of my data

Comment: I mean in your output result. 4 first column are exact the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is you create a month table. 100 years will need 1200 rows

allMonths

```
 month_id
 date
```

[How can I get a table of dates from the first day of the month, two months ago, to yesterday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160188/how-can-i-get-a-table-of-dates-from-the-first-day-of-the-month-two-months-ago)

```
SELECT 
      YT.id, 
      YT.ref_dt, 
      YT.start_dt, 
      YT.end_dt, 
      MONTHS_BETWEEN(YT.ref_dt, allDates.date) as MONTHDIFF
FROM YourTable YT
INNER JOIN allDates
        ON allDates BETWEEEN YT.START_DT AND YT.END_DT
```

Comment: thanks this works - generating that table of numbers for the month reference was the key